# How to get parts of JSON object

Tags: ruby

I get `TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer` Couldn't figure out what is wrong here.

```
require 'json'

h = '{"name":[{"first":"first ", "last":"last"}], "age":2}'
h = JSON.parse(h)

class C
  def fullname(p)       
    first(p["name"]) + last(p["name"])
  end  
  def age(p)
    p["age"]
  end

private
  def first(name)
    name["first"]
  end
  def last(name)
    name["last"]
  end
 end

C.new.age(h) #=>  2
C.new.fullname(h) #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name is an array, you have two options:

**Option A:**

Give fullname an element of the array:

```
def fullname(elem)       
   first(elem) + last(elem)
end
```

And call it with

```
C.fullname(p.first)
```

for instance

**Option B:**

Assume that it's always the first element of the array in fullname

```
def fullname(p)
   name=p["name"].first
   first(name) + last(name)
end
```

Don't be confused by Array.first which is Array[0] and your 'first' function

Comment: @sawa it's because the interpreter try to transform a string ("first") into an index in an array. The same will happens with [1,2,3]["name"]

Comment: My comment applied to OP's question as stated before the edit. Now, the question has changed, and your answer has no problem. I didn't realize that when I wrote you a comment, and I do not even know whether your answer was posted before or after the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `h["name"]` is `name = [{"first" => "first ", "last"  => "last"}]`, which is an array. You cannot apply `name["first"]` or `name["last"]`. The argument passed to an array has to be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

`"name"` is an Array. `fullname(p)` should read

```
first(p["name"][0]) + last(p["name"][0])
```